# How to match the coordinates of cv2 with matplotlip graph | Python |

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, scaling, bounding-box

here I'm trying to normalize the bouding box coordinates, the coordinates of the bounding box using opencv, the
bounding box coordinates are: [62, 1714, 1598, 2129]
shape of the image in opencv: [2339, 1654]

And now have to match the same coordinate when i open the image using matplotlib
the x and y extent of matplotlib is: [595.2, 841.92]

Is there any possible way to rescale the coordinates?

Comment: you need to make your issue reproducible. that means code and data. use pictures to show what you mean.

Comment: Do not open the same question multiple times.